# Copy-Item throws UnauthorizedAccessException within Powershell for NFS mounted disk

Tags: powershell, nfs, copy-item

I've run into an interesting problem that I can't seem to resolve. I have a Windows 10 system with an NFS-mounted drive that I've configured using the instructions [here](https://graspingtech.com/mount-nfs-share-windows-10/). Within File Explorer, I'm able to copy and create files and directories on the mounted Z: drive. However, if I try to use the `Copy-Item` command from within PowerShell, I receive the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\steve\Desktop> Copy-Item -Path "D:\source\2018_07_11\12345\0001.voc" -Destination "Z:\documents\2018\08\28\0001.voc" -Force -verbose

VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\source\
2018_07_11\12345\0001.voc Destination: Z:\documents\2018\08\28\0001.voc".
Copy-Item : Access to the path 'Z:\documents\2018\08\28\0001.voc' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item -Path "D:\source\2018_07_11\12345\0001.voc" -Destination ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (D:\source\2018_07_11\12345\0001.voc:FileInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Within PowerShell, I'm able to create directories using `mkdir`, as well as text documents using `New-Item` within the mounted drive. Only the `Copy-Item` command seems to throw this error.

Answer (score 1):

So I believe I've found a workaround to this problem. Interestingly, the source file did present part of the issue - because the file was located on a DVD, it had the `ReadOnly` attribute set on the file. This was not an issue copying the file from the DVD to a local disk, however it does seem to cause the `PermissionDenied` problem when doing the copy from the DVD to the NFS mount directly.

Additionally, after copying the file from the DVD and saving on the local disk, the `ReadOnly` flag was still set, and so not allowing the file to be copied to the NFS mount. After removing the `ReadOnly` attribute from the file, I was then able to copy it over to the NFS drive. So it appears that I'll need to copy the files off of the DVD to a local directory, remove the `ReadOnly` attribute, then copy to the NFS drive.

For completeness: the NFS server is a CentOS 7 system running [GlusterFS](https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/) and exporting out its drives using [NFS-Ganesha](https://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

(I would have left a comment but my reputation is not high enough)

Error messages seem conflicting. First:
  "Access to the path 'Z:\documents\2018\08\28\0001.voc' is denied."
Then: 
  "PermissionDenied: (D:\source\2018_07_11\12345\0001.voc:FileInfo)"

Are you sure you have sufficient access to the source file? Could you make a test with another source file? have you tried to run Powershell with elevated privileges?

Comment: To answer a couple of your questions: I am able to copy the source file to a local directory. I then try to copy that local file to the Z: path and get the same error. I then tried to run PS as admin; had to run New-PSDrive to get the mount point, however still received the same error trying to copy to Z: